# Running pyttsx3 (espeak) text-to-speech in docker container creates awful sound quality

Tags: python, docker, audio, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I am trying to run [pyttsx3](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/) (which runs on espeak) and create .mp3 files with it in python3.10.
The problem is that the created audio files have truly inaudible sound quality as can be seen/heard here: https://vocaroo.com/15u2rs6hOJXR
This problem only occurs when building the app as a docker image and then running said image using `docker run mybot:latest`. When running the app locally everything works fine

The docker file I am using is:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster
ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY . /bot
RUN cd /bot
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    fonts-liberation \
    libasound2 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libatspi2.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libdrm2 \
    libgbm1 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libwayland-client0 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxkbcommon0 \
    libxrandr2 \
    xdg-utils \
    libu2f-udev \
    libvulkan1 \
    espeak \
    ffmpeg \
    alsa-utils \
    libespeak1 \
    curl
RUN curl -LO  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
WORKDIR /bot
EXPOSE 3308
CMD [ "python3", "appHandler.py", "start", "dev" ]
```

There is no errors or warnings logged anywhere.

Does anyone know what could be the problem here? I havent found anything on this topic so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" this issue and will leave this here in case anyone else ever encounters this problem:
Alright, so after another day of research and trying stuff out I found out why this is the case. 
Pyttsx3 needs an engine (driver) to translate text to speech. It will use the standard driver of the OS if not specified. Since I was running on OSX it defaulted to `NSSpeechSynthesizer`, but when I ran the app in docker the OS changes to linux and the default driver became `espeak`. 
`NSSpeechSynthesizer` and `espeak` have huge differences in quality, meaning `espeak` sounds like a drunk robot.
There is **no way to use NSSpeechSynthesizer in docker** as it is OSX exclusive.
Since I didnt like the result of `espeak` at all I decided to switch from using `pyttsx3` to using `AWS polly`, which can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/polly/) and has amazing quality, is easy to use and very cheap for small developers like myself.